# How to implement dependant columns in hypothesis dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, python-hypothesis

I am using hypothesis dataframes to implement a dataframe in which start_time and end_time are two columns. Here is a chunck:

```py
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import logging
import datetime

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import column, data_frames, range_indexes

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

datetime_st = st.integers(
    min_value=(current_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)).timestamp(),
    max_value=(current_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=20)).timestamp(),
)

df_columns = {
    # other fields omitted
    "start_time": {"elements": datetime_st, "unique": False},
    "end_time": {"elements": datetime_st, "unique": False},
}
test_dfs = data_frames(
    index=range_indexes(min_size=20, max_size=100),
    columns=[column(key, **value) for key, value in df_columns.items()],
)

@given(df=test_dfs)
def test_hyothesis(df):
    logging.info(df)
    assert 1
```

I am not able to find a solution to assert that each start_time should be greater than its corresponding end_time by atleast delta. I have tried `composite`, but I am not sure on how to implement it on each rows of the `dataframes`.

Is there a way that I enforce the delta as a rule when initialising start_time and end_time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to generate a dataframe of two time-stamp columns, where the difference between the first one and the second one is at least 3600 seconds (or some other amount of time). I'm using `st.flatmap` for that.

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import column, data_frames, range_indexes, columns

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()

MIN_DIFF_SECONDS = 3600

two_timestamps_with_diff = st.integers(
    min_value = current_time + 3600 * 4, 
    max_value = current_time + 4600 * 20).flatmap(
    lambda n: st.tuples(
       st.integers(min_value = n, max_value=n), 
       st.integers(min_value = n + MIN_DIFF_SECONDS, max_value = n + 3600*10)
   ))

# sample code to examine the results of this strategy
# for _ in range(10):
#     x, y = two_timestamps_with_diff.example()
#     print(x, y, y-x)
    
test_dfs = data_frames(
    index=range_indexes(min_size=20, max_size=100),
    columns=columns(["start_time", "end_time"], dtype=int),
    rows=two_timestamps_with_diff, 
)

# sample code to examine the results of this strategy
# res = test_dfs.example()
# res.assign(d = res.end_time - res.start_time)

# a test with an assertion that validates this constraint. 
@given(df=test_dfs)
def test_hyothesis(df):
    logging.info(df)
    assert ((df.end_time - df.start_time) >= MIN_DIFF_SECONDS).all()
    
# run the test. It passes. 
test_hyothesis()
```

---

If you'd like to add additional columns to the autogenerated dataframe, do the following (the new columns are 'a' and 'b' in this example):

```
from hypothesis.strategies import composite

@composite
def test_df_with_additional_columns(draw, elements=test_dfs):
    df = draw(test_dfs)
    
    class GetIndex(st.SearchStrategy[pd.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex]): 
        def do_draw(self, _):
            return df.index    
    
    more_col_strategy = data_frames([column('A', dtype=int), 
                                     column('B', dtype=float)], 
                                    index = GetIndex()
                                   )
    
    more_cols = draw(more_col_strategy)
    
    return pd.concat([df, more_cols], axis=1)

test_df_with_additional_columns().example()
```

Comment: This works after the generation of the df. Is there a way that I enforce this assertion as a rule when initialising start_time and end_time?

Comment: Aha. I now understand what you're looking for. You'd like to only generate data where start_time + CONSTANT < end_time?

Comment: Have a look at this new answer. Let me know if it helps. (the question is cool, by the way :)

Comment: Thanks! It does solve it. 
I was occupied yesterday to add additional columns to the same logic.

Comment: Bringing this thread up, I am not able to implement the case when there are other fields in df_columns apart from start_time and end_time

Comment: Could you provide an example of other columns you'd like to generate?

Comment: `"name": {"elements": some_name_function, "unique": True}, "field1": {"elements": field1_fucntion, "unique": False},...` and so on. They are independant of the start_time and end_time